# Multi-moduled project not running

Tags: spring, maven, module, multi-module

I have a project with parent module /onlinetore/ it has spring boot modules bookstore and admin , which has been working properly because both application don't share much just a url path defined in app.properties , but now I created a domain module, all domain objects have been imported from this new module to bookstore with no errors, but when I run the bookstore it shows totally nothing says access denied , I cant view anything and no errors is being displayed ,
earlier it showed ,something about a unique order must be used so I added @Order to securityConfig and now no trace of where the problem might be coming from.
Any suggestions on what I can check?

/onlinestore/

/admin/

bookstore/
pom.-dependency on domain

domain/
pom - dependency on parant

My online store pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.modular</groupId>
    <artifactId>onlinestore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>admin</module>
        <module>bookstore</module>
        <module>domain</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>onlinestore</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The bookstore pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>onlinestore</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.modular</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>

    <modules>
      <module>../domain</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.modular</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-M3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- this is added to check weather user logged in or not-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.196</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!--for checking -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${mockito.version}</version>-->
        <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the domain pom, currently I'm not testing the integration of domain and bookstore so I will not be posting the admin pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>onlinestore</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.modular</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>

<dependencies>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

this is my main class config

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.modular.domain","com.domain.domain"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.bookstore.services","com.domain.domain",
"com.bookstore.utility","com.domain.domain.security","com.bookstore.repository"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.bookstore.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BookstoreApplications implements CommandLineRunner {
```

Comment: Can you update your post with directory structure and POM files ?

Comment: @KedarJoshi I have

Comment: I meant the full directory structure and contents of the POM files

Comment: I just posted @KedarJoshi

Comment: The only thing weird about this configuration is that you have added `domain` as dependency and module simultaneously in `bookstore` POM.

By the way what exactly is the exception ?

Comment: There is know error it just doesn't show anything in local host